# Angular behaving weird with $routeChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm using a third-party library to handle my authentication, and in my logout function I call `$location.url('/login')`.

However, in my app module, I'm trying to change some CSS based on the current route. The function that does this looks like this:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $route) {
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(currentRoute, previousRoute){
    //Change page css, based on Route information
    $rootScope.isLogin = {
        status: $route.current.$$route.isLogin.status
    };
});
});
```

In my config, I've also specified some routes based on ngRoute with a parameter that tells me if the current page is a login page or not.

```
    $routeProvider.
    when('/route1', {
        templateUrl: './partials/route1.html',
        controller: 'Route1Ctrl',
        isLogin: { status: false }
    }).
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: './partials/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        isLogin: { status: true }
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
```

Now, whenever I call the logout function, I am getting a typeerror: `Cannot read property 'isLogin' of undefined`, which basically tells me that `$route.current.$$route.isLogin.status` is unset. Considering I'm using the event $routeChangeSuccess I don't understand why it isn't being set yet.

Can someone see where I'm not doing this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `'isLogin' of undefined` is saying that `$$route` is `undefined`. You shouldn't use properties that starting from `$$` since they are internal for Angular. Once you have defined `isLogout` on route, you can access it directly by `$route.current.isLogout`.

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/route1', {
        template: '<h1>Template 1</h1>',
        isLogin: { status: false }
      }).
      when('/route2', {
        template: '<h1>Template 2</h1>',
        isLogin: { status: true }
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/route1'
      });
  }]).
  run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute){
      if(!currentRoute.redirectTo) { // <= "otherwise" is a route as well, so $routeChangeSuccess is also triggered. However, it does not have `isLogin` property, so filter out this case.
        $rootScope.isLogin = {
          status: currentRoute.isLogin.status
        };
      }
    });
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R4DSz7kV56zpM9EXpNLm?p=preview

***Edit:***

Handler of `$routeChangeSuccess` event receives current route as a second parameter. That means that you may use it directly like `currentRoute.isLogin` instead of injecting `$route` service to the `run` block and using it like `$route.current.isLogin`.

Another thing that should be mentioned is that `otherwise` in `$routeProvider`'s configuration is also a route. Therefore, in case router resolves a new current route as `otherwise` a `$routeChangeSuccess` event is fired as well (actually it will be fired twice: first time for `otherwise` route and second for the rout to which it redirect's to). Since `otherwise` route does not have a `isLogin` property, you should filter this case out before trying to access `currentRoute.isLogin`.

Comment: I wasn't sure! Thanks. Somehow, when I checked the variables available, I only noticed $$route.

Comment: Alright, was testing a bit now, and I am still getting errors `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`. Maybe it happens when I hit a / route?

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen I have edited the post including code snippet, plunker and added some comments regarding the issue with `otherwise` route